# Multiple columns in VS 2008 express C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I want to make an application in which listBox output would have columns like this:

```
Name   |Priority | Date
Task 1 |High     | Today
Task 2 |High     | Today
Task 3 |High     | Today
Task 4 |High     | Today
```

But I don't seem to find a way to input data into different columns.

How to do that in VS C++ 2008 express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list *box* won't do that (conveniently at all, anyway). You want a [list *control*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx) in report view. Since Express doesn't include MFC, you'll have to do that using the raw Win32 API (or do it from some other language such as C# using WinForms, which I'd recommend against).

Comment: WinForms is supported in C++ (even with a designer). Also, why not do it in C#? Either option is far better than the Win32 API.

Comment: WinForms is supported in C++/CLI, *not* C++ (and nobody, not even Microsoft, recommends using C++/CLI except for interoperation). I wasn't particularly recommending against C# in general, but against C# with WinForms. If you're going to use C#, you probably want WPF. I suppose WPF provides a equivalent to (or ability to use) a list control, but I don't know WPF well enough to say more than that.